# Use Tensorflow model in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have trained an LSTM model mapping 9 inputs to 7 outputs each time step using Tensorflow. Now I have reconstructed the model in Matlab, but the results (I plotted the trajectories) don't seem to be correct.

I did this by just load the trained weight-matrices of the LSTM network in Matlab. Furthermore I implemented the forward-propagation rules in Matlab by hand and plugged in the weight-matrices

```
   function [outputs,states] = unfoldNetwork(obj,inputs)

        numInputs = size(inputs,1);
        input_output = [inputs(1,:)' ; zeros(obj.num_hidden,1)];
        state = zeros(obj.num_hidden,1);

        outputs = zeros(numInputs, obj.output_dim);
        states = zeros(numInputs, obj.num_hidden);

        for i=1:numInputs

            [output,state] = fp(obj,state,input_output);
            input_output = [inputs(i,:)' ; output];

            outputs(i,:) = (obj.output_W * output + obj.output_b)'; % transfer to output-dimension
            states(i,:) = state';
        end
    end

    function [output,state] = fp(obj,state,input_output)

        i = obj.sigmoid(obj.weights(1:obj.num_hidden,:) * input_output + obj.biases(1:obj.num_hidden));
        g = tanh(obj.weights(obj.num_hidden+1:2*obj.num_hidden,:) * input_output + obj.biases(obj.num_hidden+1:2*obj.num_hidden));
        f = obj.sigmoid(obj.weights(2*obj.num_hidden+1:3*obj.num_hidden,:) * input_output + obj.biases(2*obj.num_hidden+1:3*obj.num_hidden));
        o = obj.sigmoid(obj.weights(3*obj.num_hidden+1:4*obj.num_hidden,:) * input_output + obj.biases(3*obj.num_hidden+1:4*obj.num_hidden));

        state = f.*state + i.*g;
        output = o.* tanh(state);
    end

    function [argout] = sigmoid(obj,x)
        argout = 1./(1+exp(-x));
    end
```

The network in Tensorflow is basically this

```
lstm_cell_1 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(config.n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=False)

# Get LSTM cell output
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell_1, _X, initial_state=_S, dtype=tf.float32)

# output layer
# bring it to a shape for being able to multiply with output layer matrix
outputs = tf.reshape(outputs,[-1,config.n_hidden])

final_outputs = [tf.matmul(outputs, config.W['output']) + config.biases['output'] ]
final_outputs = tf.reshape(final_outputs,[batch_size,timesteps,config.n_output]) # convert it back to sequence
```

[Ground Truth, Python prediction, and Matlab prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyIXI.png)

On the image, you can see at the beginning the prediction in Matlab do (a little bit shifted) correspond with the one in Python. After that, it gets somehow biased. I am pretty sure that the forward propagation rules and the weight matrices are correct. Because I did change some matrices or the forward-propagation rules just a little bit and after that everything gets really messy.

Comment: Sorry, is this a question?

Comment: Yes obviously there went something wrong transfering the Tensorflow model in Matlab. And what I wanted to ask is if someone -who may has more insight in Tensorflow- knows the reason for that..

Comment: Does this https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/64649-deep-learning-toolbox-converter-for-tensorflow-models help. Thanks!